# Removing Tradingview logo on Ticker Widget

Tags: javascript, html, widget, stockquotes, tradingview-api

Can someone please help me remove the tradingview marketing logo. I've tired almost everything and somehow the code get's messed up. I'm using this widget from tradingview (https://www.tradingview.com/widget/ticker/) and wanted to know if:

- remove their icon so it does not appear, and
- does not get redirected to the tradingview website.

I am not sure how to go about making it so it can appear on a website.

Comment: Hey, do you mean the logo in the header?

Comment: Does my answer answers your question?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I mean the logo in the header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For removing that, you could inject javascript code into it:

```
document.querySelector('.tv-header__link').remove();
```

`tv-header__link` is the class of the logo anchor tag...

The function `remove()` removes the querySelected element, like the name says.

[MDN Page of remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)

With `querySelector()` you can select elements with a certain class or id, so my code selects the element with a class of 'tv-header__link', which is the tradingview-logo in the header, and removes it with the help of the `remove()` function.

[MDN Page of document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

[MDN Page of element.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element/querySelector)

Comment: This doesn't work for me.. any solution on how I can go about it

Comment: @BrowynLouis Could you describe the problem you are facing? In which way does it not work, do you have an error message?